# Como usar valor de i no for em uma função?

Tags: python, loop, for

Tenho o seguinte código:

```py
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Identificador')).select_by_visible_text('Maio/2019')
form = driver.find_element_by_name('Formulario')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='Formulario']/input[@type='submit'][@value='Ok']").click()
```

Gostaria de automatizar isso com um `for` para vários meses e anos.

```py
month = ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro",
         "Novembro", "Dezembro"]

year_today = datetime.date.today().year

year = range(2007,year_today,1)

for i in year:
    for j in month:
        print('Downloading',j,i)
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Identificador')).select_by_visible_text('Maio/2019')
form = driver.find_element_by_name('Formulario')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@name='Formulario']/input[@type='submit'][@value='Ok']").click()
```

Como eu substituo "Maio/2019" por valores de month e year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a concatenação de strings fazendo um cast no year

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('Identificador')).select_by_visible_text(j+'/'+str(i))
```

Comment: Ah, entendi como funciona! Obrigado! Só precisei trocar o `year` por `i`. Valeu!

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu!